# Как скопировать данные поля одной таблицы в поле другой?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `serial` с полем `created_at` и таблица `serials` c полем `created_at`.

Как можно скопировать с заменой данные поля `created_at` таблицы `serials` в поле `created_at` таблицы `serial`?

Comment: Какая-то связь по этим таблицам есть? Т.е. взяв данные из одной таблицы, можно выйти на запись другой? К примеру, может, `ID` совпадают...

Comment: `update table1 set created_at=(select created_at from table2 where table2.id=table1.id)` как то так например

Answer (score 0):

Для копирования данных из одного поля в другое в разных таблицах SQL можно использовать оператор UPDATE с помощью команды SELECT для выбора данных из одной таблицы и их обновления в другой. В вашем случае, для копирования данных поля `created_at` из таблицы `serials` в таблицу `serial` вы можете воспользоваться следующим SQL-запросом:

```sql
UPDATE serial
SET serial.created_at = serials.created_at
FROM serials
WHERE <условие соответствия записей>;
```

Этот запрос обновит поле `created_at` в таблице `serial` данными из поля `created_at` таблицы `serials`. Замените <условие соответствия записей> на условие, по которому строки в таблицах `serial` и `serials` должны соответствовать друг другу. Это может быть условие на основе ключевых столбцов, например, если есть уникальный идентификатор, или другое соответствующее условие, которое определит, какие строки из `serials` должны быть скопированы в `serial`.

Пример использования условия для выборки и обновления данных может выглядеть так, например, если в обеих таблицах есть поле `serial_id`, который уникально идентифицирует запись:

```sql
UPDATE serial
SET serial.created_at = serials.created_at
FROM serials
WHERE serials.serial_id = serial.serial_id;
```

Можно добавить дополнительные условия, например, на `serials.created_at`:

```sql
UPDATE serial
SET serial.created_at = serials.created_at
FROM serials
WHERE serials.serial_id = serial.serial_id
AND serials.created_at = '2023-01-01'; -- Сравниваем с определенной датой (здесь '2023-01-01')
```